# Radiogroup in a listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-radiogroup

I have a listview with dynamic radio buttons(it will be creating based on size of some questions in listview i.e, for first question i Have 4 radio buttons second question may have 3 radio buttons.....).My problem is when User select choose the answers using radio buttons I need submit those form. So how can I achieve those listview data along with selected answers. Also I need to check for question is answered or not(means check radio group). When I submit I want that whole data.Can anyone help me on this.

this is my getview

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list_bradenscale_entry, null);

    viewHolder.txtQuestionHeadName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_question_name);
    viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption4 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    viewHolder.txtQuestionHeadHint = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_question_hint);
    viewHolder.txtOption1Hint = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_option1Hint);
    viewHolder.txtOption2Hint = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_option2Hint);
    viewHolder.txtOption3Hint = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_option3Hint);
    viewHolder.txtOption4Hint = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_option4Hint);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    selectedList = new 
    final DataContractQuestionList myDataitem = arrData.get(position);
    viewHolder.txtQuestionHeadName.setText(myDataitem.QuestionTitle);
    viewHolder.txtQuestionHeadHint.setText(myDataitem.QuestionHint);


    viewHolder.radioButtonOption1.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).OptionTitle);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption2.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).OptionTitle);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption3.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).OptionTitle);
    viewHolder.txtOption1Hint.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).OptionHint);
    viewHolder.txtOption2Hint.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).OptionHint);
    viewHolder.txtOption3Hint.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).OptionHint);
    if (myDataitem.QuestionOptions.size() < 4) {
        viewHolder.radioButtonOption4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.txtOption4Hint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.radioButtonOption4.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).OptionTitle);
        viewHolder.txtOption4Hint.setText(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).OptionHint);
        viewHolder.radioButtonOption4.setChecked(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).checkedStatus);

    }


    viewHolder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int selectedRadioButton = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = group.findViewById(selectedRadioButton);
            int radioId = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);

            if (radioId / 2 == 0) {
                viewHolder.radioButtonOption1.setChecked(true);
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).checkedStatus = true;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).checkedStatus = false;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).checkedStatus = false;
                if (myDataitem.QuestionOptions.size() == 4) {

                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).checkedStatus = false;
                }
            } else if (radioId / 2 == 1) {
                viewHolder.radioButtonOption2.setChecked(true);
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).checkedStatus = false;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).checkedStatus = true;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).checkedStatus = false;
                if (myDataitem.QuestionOptions.size() == 4) {

                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).checkedStatus = false;
                }
            } else if (radioId / 2 == 2) {
                viewHolder.radioButtonOption3.setChecked(true);
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).checkedStatus = false;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).checkedStatus = false;
                myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).checkedStatus = true;
                if (myDataitem.QuestionOptions.size() == 4) {

                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).checkedStatus = false;
                }
            } else if (radioId / 2 == 3) {
                if (myDataitem.QuestionOptions.size() == 4) {
                    viewHolder.radioButtonOption4.setChecked(true);
                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).checkedStatus = false;
                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).checkedStatus = false;
                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).checkedStatus = false;
                    myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(3).checkedStatus = true;

                }
            }

        }
    });


    viewHolder.radioButtonOption1.setChecked(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(0).checkedStatus);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption2.setChecked(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(1).checkedStatus);
    viewHolder.radioButtonOption3.setChecked(myDataitem.QuestionOptions.get(2).checkedStatus);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Use the same array to store selected status. Then based on the status you can get the checked data and send.

Comment: Posted my getview()

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter **getView()** method, attach the listener to your radio button while rendering your list item. In the on checked event, change the attribute of your object. Your activity can just access to the same objects list and retrieve the latest state of questionnaire.

```
rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        // This will get the radiobutton that has changed in its check state
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
        // This puts the value (true/false) into the variable
        boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
        // If the radiobutton that has changed in check state is now checked...
        if (isChecked)
        {
            //Change your object's attribute here
            question.answer = "xxxx";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If the question is not answered, how rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener() will called?

Comment: if it is not answered, just remain the default state of the question e.g. answered = false. Doesn't it work?